# How to implement subscript operators in Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm writing a parser in Parsec. Left-recursive productions like E -> E + E cannot be written easily in an LL parser, so Parsec provides `buildExpressionParser`, which supports infix, postfix and prefix operators. But what about subscript operators?

How would E -> E [E] be implemented?
If I could consume the closing bracket without consuming the second expression, then I could emulate it with an Infix table entry for `buildExpressionParser`. Thoughts?

Edit: I know there is an algorithm for left-recursion elimination that will most likely work for my grammar. I'm looking for something easy, or well-abstracted (such as `buildExpressionParser`). Otherwise I'll just use Happy.

Comment: I would recommend against using happy for this or basically any reason.  Happy sidesteps Haskell's power of abstraction.

Comment: Just do it as a `Postfix` with `buildExpressionParser`.

Comment: how does postfix help? with that I can match the closing bracket, but no way of matching the opening one...

Comment: `Postfix :: ParsecT s u m (a -> a) -> Operator s u m a`, so a postfix operator can be an arbitrary parser, not just a single character.  For example, you could use `brackets lex parseExpr` (where `lex` is a `TokenParser`) as an argument to `Postfix`.

Comment: i just noticed now that Postfix and Prefix are **unary**. then i guess it could work...

Comment: thanks, somehow i didn't notice they were unary and i thought you wanted me to do some kind of RPN calculator :D

Comment: i got it to work. if you want to bother writing a concise answer, i'll accept it for you. turns out postfix is actually more generic than infix (postfix +E == infix +), and prefix is only there for helping with precedence, since prefix operators do not yield left-recursive rules.

Comment: @BruceBerry feel free to answer the question with your own solution!

Answer (score 1):

In our project we manually eliminated left recursion from the expressions. This works the following way:

We created a generic form of expressions, that is parameterized by the term parser:

```
expressionGen :: MParser (Expr LocInfo) -> MParser (Expr LocInfo)
expressionGen term = buildExpressionParser precedenceTable term <?> "expression"
  where precedenceTable = -- unary, binary expressions
```

We have a normal term parser, and a term parser free of recursive rules. With that, we can parse (multiple) subscript operators:

```
term :: MParser (Expr LocInfo)
term = do indBase <- termNoArray
          indexes <- many $ (brackets expression >>= return)
          return -- semantics
        <?> "term"

termNoArray :: MParser (Expr LocInfo)
termNoArray = -- normal terms
```

Finally, we have a topmost parser for expressions: `expression = expressionGen term`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to treat the postfix subscript operator as a one whole thing, including the index expression.

In `megaparsec/parsec-combinators` terms:

```hs
pExpr = makeExprParser pTerm operatorTable

...

parseSubscr :: Operator Parser Expr
parseSubscr =
  Postfix $ do
    symbol space "["
    index <- pExpr
    symbol space "]"
    pure $ \parent ->
      Subscript parent index
```